# Laravel 5.1 doesn't allow you to pass in url params (is there configuration)

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, testing, laravel-5.1

Consider the following test:

```
public function it_should_contain_a_list_of_investors_who_belong_to_one_or_more_investment() {
    $this->createInvestment();

    $investor = factory(User::class)->create([
        'role_id' => 4
    ]);

    $response = $this->actingAs($investor)
                     ->call('GET', 'api/v1/investors?include=investments');

    dd(json_decode($response->getContent()));
    $this->assertNotEmpty(json_decode($response->getContent()));
}
```

Now consider the following action this test is calling:

```
public function getAllInvestorsForCompany($slug)
{
    $users = $this->investorEntity->usersForCompany($slug);

    $resource = new Collection($users, new InvestorTransformer, 'investor');
    dd($_GET);
    if (isset($_GET['include'])) {
        $usersData = $this->manager->parseIncludes($_GET['include'])->createData($resource)->toArray();
    } else {
        $usersData = $this->manager->createData($resource)->toArray();
    }

    return response()->json($usersData);
}
```

Note the `dd`, the `$_GET` returns []

Lets do the same test in the browser:

```
array:1 [▼
  "include" => "investments.offering.company"
]
```

Ok so in the browser I get back investments.offering.company, because that is what I am passing in as the `?include=` But in the test its like laravel ignores the ?include and moves on.

is this a default behaviour of laravel 5.1 tests and if so how do I shut it off?

Comment: `$_GET` will not be populated during a console request because your console application doesn't actually _make_ requests. It instead runs the requested action through the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd argument for `call` is for parameters.

```
$response = $this->actingAs($investor)
    ->call('GET', 'api/v1/investors', ['include' => 'investments']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `$_GET`, `$_POST`, or `$_REQUEST` in Laravel controllers. You should use the `Request` facade:

```
public function getAllInvestorsForCompany($slug)
{
    $users = $this->investorEntity->usersForCompany($slug);

    $resource = new Collection($users, new InvestorTransformer, 'investor');

    if (Request::input('include')) {
        $usersData = $this->manager->parseIncludes(Request::input('include'))->createData($resource)->toArray();
    } else {
        $usersData = $this->manager->createData($resource)->toArray();
    }

    return response()->json($usersData);
}
```

When testing, Laravel doesn't *actually* make HTTP calls - it creates a `Request` object, and then passes that to the routing controller, which is why those variables aren't actually available.

Using the `Request` facade also allows you to do things like set a default if the input doesn't exist, and handles multiple input forms (like AngularJS which sends data as JSON in the request body, instead of as POST or GET parameters).

Comment: So How do I set the `?include=` using the Request object?

Comment: Just send the URL as you are. The `Request` object will parse the query string and turn it into parameters automatically. Internally it uses the `Request` object from `Symfony`, and then adds some extra functionality on top. See the [Symfony Source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L308)

Comment: You could also send an associative array or parameters as your third item in the `call` method, and that will take precedence over anything passed in the querystring, but either will work just fine.